# Anaconda iPython Notebook default directory with multiple versions of Python

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder

I have Anaconda installed with two environments py27 and py34. I been trying to create two default directories for iPython notebook one for py24 (e.g. iPython Notebooks py27) and one for py34 (e.g. iPython Notebooks py34) but so far no luck.

Tried creating different profiles, but anaconda keep overriding when I launch iPython notebook from console.

So my question is how to set up different default iPython Notebook directories for different versions of python ?

Comment: In the console, the default notebook directory is normally where you start it. Can you just `cd` into the folder you want and start `ipython notebook` from there?

Comment: I usually launch iPython Notebook using Anaconda Launcher.

Comment: You can try setting `NotebookApp.notebook_dir` in config ([config docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/intro.html), [notebook config options](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/options/notebook.html)), but I think the Anaconda launcher might override it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows.

1 navigate to notebook directory.

2 hold shift and right click -> open  command window here

3 type commands.

```
activate py34 
ipython notebook
```